# HowTo show values of cells in array

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried reaseaching with Google-Fu but was not able to make this work:

```
Sub LoopRange()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

For Each rCell In rRng.Rows
    Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
Next rCell

End Sub
```

It does show the addresses in the Immediate window in the format of: 
$A$1
$A$2 
...

But it returns no values, numbers or text.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Looks fine i ran it and tested and had no issues. Are you sure those cells aren't actually just blank? Also noticed a good amount of distance between the address and value in the window, make sure the window is wide enough to view both?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")
```

This references the VBA object `Sheet1` which is almost assuredly different than the sheet you are looking at. This may be in a different order or named differently.

Try one of

```
Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6")  'This is the current sheet
Set rRng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A6")  'This is the sheet in index 1 in your workbook, left to right
Set rRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6") 'This is the sheet named "Sheet1"
```

depending on what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two more values to `Debug.Print` namely `rCell.Parent.Parent.Name, rCell.Parent.Name` which shows you the workbook name and sheet name to which rcell is pointing to. This will help you to identify the issue.

```
 Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Rows
        Debug.Print rCell.Parent.Parent.Name, rCell.Parent.Name, rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

It always better to specify the workbook because there can be multiple workbook open.

```
 Set rRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A6")
```

HTH